# Circular Linked list concatenation complexity

Tags: linked-list, complexity-theory, big-o, adt

Suppose you have two circular linked lists , one is of size `M` and the other is of size `N` and  `M < N`. If you don't know which list is of size `M`, what is the worst-case complexity to concatenate the two lists into a single list?

I was thinking `O(M)` but that is not correct. And no, I guess there is no specific place to concatenate at.

Comment: What's your reasoning, and what do you mean by a list of "size N and M"?

Comment: is there a specific place to do the concatenation at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no further restrictions, and your lists are mutable (like normal linked lists in languages like C, C#, Java, ...), just split the two lists open at whatever nodes you have and join them together (involves up to four nodes). Since it's homework, I leave working out the complexity to you, but it should be easy, there's a strong hint in the preceding.

If the lists are immutable, as would normally be the case in a pure functional language, you'd have to copy a number of nodes and get a different complexity. What complexity exactly would depend on restrictions on the sort of result (e.g. does it have to be a circular linked list?).